# The last value in my list will not convert into integer

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, integer

I am writing a code in which I take values from a user until they enter 'q'. I then have to print the EVEN numbers out in ascending order. I how to do the program, I just have run into a minor problem I do not know how to solve.

My code is:

```
integer = []
g = 7
while g > 1:                # Initiate loop
    num = input('Enter an integer or press q to quit.  ')
    if num == 'q':
        break
    integer = list(map(int, integer))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        integer.append(num)


integer.sort()
print(integer)
```

Running this code gives me the error that not all strings have converted. So I then erased the second if statement:

```
 if num % 2 == 0:
        integer.append(num)
```

Erasing this I can see that the last value in the list will not convert into an integer. I do not know why that is and I have tried numerous string-list to integer-list conversions and they all never convert the last value. Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Its a bad practice to call your variable after types names - e.g `integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
integer = []
g = 7
while g > 1:                # Initiate loop
    num = input('Enter an integer or press q to quit.  ')
    if num == 'q':
        break
    num = int(num) #convert input to integer
    if num % 2 == 0:
        integer.append(num)


integer.sort()
print(integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
evens = []

while True:                # Initiate infinite loop
    num = input('Enter an integer or press q to quit.  ')

    if num == 'q':
        break

    num = int(num)  #convert the num to int

    if num % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(num)


evens.sort()
print(evens)
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is `num` is a string from user input, you must convert it to an integer like this

```py
if int(num) % 2 == 0:
    integer.append(int(num))
```